# How to use a second router to improve wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, netgear-router

I have a NETGEAR nighthawk rax54s WiFi router and a nighthawk R7000 WiFi router. I want to increase the WiFi range how can I join the two routers? Also, I would prefer to have them using the same ssids so that they appear as to be just one set of ssids for the network.

Comment: If the second one has the extender function in the firmware it should be easy, otherwise all you can do is to have a secondary AP. How to set it up differs by model/firmware quite a lot. So, the first thing is to read the user's manuals.

Comment: The best way to join the routers is to avoid doing so through WIFI as it eats away your spectrum re-transmitting the packet.  The ideal is to run a cable between them.  If this is not possible, sometimes you can use Ethernet over Powerline to achieve the same result.

Comment: I already was using Ethernet as the backbone for the link.

Comment: I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Nighthawk R7000 seems to support reapeating/extending mode. Check the instructions in the official [manual](https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/R7000/R7000_UM.pdf) on page 86:

> **Note:** You cannot use the WPA2-PSK (AES), WPA-PSK (TKIP) + WPA-PSK (AED), or WPA/WPA2 Enterprise security modes if you want to enable
> this mode. You also cannot select the Auto channel selection mode.
>
> **To set up the router in repeating mode:**
>
> 1. Make a note of the WiFi settings of the other router to which this router will connect. You must know the SSID, WiFi security mode,
>    wireless password, and operating frequency (either 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz).
> 2. Launch a web browser from a computer or mobile device that is connected to the network.
> 3. Enter http://www.routerlogin.net. A login window opens.
> 4. Enter the router user name and password. The user name is `admin`. The default password is `password`. The user name and password are
>    case-sensitive. The BASIC Home page displays.
> 5. Select <kbd>ADVANCED</kbd> > <kbd>Advanced Setup</kbd> > <kbd>Router/ AP / Bridge Mode</kbd>. The Router / AP / Bridge Mode page displays.
> 6. Select <kbd>Repeating Mode</kbd>. The page adjusts.
> 7. Select the <kbd>Enable Wireless Repeating Function</kbd> check box.
> 8. In the <kbd>Repeater IP Address</kbd> field, enter the IP address of the repeater router. This IP address must be in the same subnet as the
>    base station, but different from the LAN IP address of the base
>    station.
> 9. To prevent wireless clients from associating with the repeater and allow LAN client associations only, select <kbd>Disable Wireless Client
>    Association</kbd>. You can leave the check box cleared if you prefer
>    wireless clients to be able to associate with the repeater.
> 10. In the <kbd>Base Station MAC Address</kbd> field, enter the MAC addresses for the access point that will be the base station.
> 11. Click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button. Your settings are saved.
> 12. Verify connectivity across the LANs. A computer on any wireless or wired LAN segment of the router can connect to the Internet or share
>     files and printers with any other computer or server connected to the
>     other base station.